# How to set Routes for APIs

Tags: node.js, routes

I am building an API to manage meetups with nodeJS. I have build an endpoint with the route "**/meetups/:id/**" to fetch a specific meetup record by its id. And then I want to fetch all the upcoming meetup records and I tried to use "**/meetups/upcoming/**" but when I query it, I get the not found error (404). It seems like the second route is not recognised.

[Here is  the code defining the two routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keqk8.png)

[the request from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8U6w.png)

Any help on how can I handle that?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code where you define the routes.

Comment: I add an image of the code where I define the two routes in the question post.

Comment: I add the code where I define the two routes in the question post.//get a specific meetup
app.get('/api/v1/meetups/:id', (req,res)=>{
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

  db.meetups.forEach(function(meetup){
    if(meetup.id === id){
      return res.status(200).send({})
    }
  });
  return res.status(404).send({});
});
//get all upcoming meetups
app.get('/api/v1/meetups/upcoming', (req,res)=>{
  var today = new Date();
  const upcomings = db.meetups.map(function(meetup){
    if(meetup.happeningOn > today){
      return meetup;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Route is '/api/v1/meetups/upcoming/all'. Move res.status outside the map function.

EDIT: you'll have to change the route which has to be different from api/v1/meetups/:id. Reason is when route '/api/v1/meetups/upcoming' is requested express sees it as the same route as before and takes 'upcoming' as the parameter.

```
app.get("/api/v1/meetups/upcoming/all", function(req, res) {
    var today = new Date();

    var upcomings = db.meetups.map(function(meetup) {
        if(meetup.happeningOn > today) {
            return meetup;
        }
    });

    res.status(200).send({
        status: 200,
        data: upcomings
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that error but the result remain the same, I am getting 404 error which comes from the first route '/api/v1/meetups/:id'

Comment: Can you mention how you send the GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `res.status` piece outside of the `const upcomings` definition.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not getting the good result out of it.

Comment: What do you mean by good result? Can you edit your question with the latest code/changes you have?

Comment: I have done it. There are two routes, the first one which takes an id as a parameter and retreive a specific meetup and the second one which which have to retreive all upcoming meetups